# Create a PDF from crystal report's RPT file and attach the generated PDF file in SQL's db mail system through a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report's .rpt file and what I need is that the PDF generated from this rpt file should be attached in the mail that I will be sending using sp_send_dbmail.

So is it possible to do this entire operation within a stored procedure?

Comment: Natively with tsql - no. By adding extensions (like clr) to the engine - perhaps.

Comment: @SMor Can you please share me a reference of how it can be done?